# Can we run Google Maps V2 in an emulator?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I know that it didn't used to be possible to run an app in the emulator that used Google Maps V2 API because that also requires Google Play Services.  I see a lot of this issue being discussed where I am told that it can't be done but those messages are all at least two years old.

I'm using Android Studio and have built a Nexus 5 emulator running Google API 22 armeabi-v7a because I need to test my app on Android 5.0 and I don't have a phone with that level.  But, of course, this emulator flunks my isGooglePlayServicesAvailable test.

This is my AVD details.  It was my understanding that selecting a Google API would do the trick . . .
[image]

Is it possible today to build an emulator that will run all this?
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Genymotion is free and supports 5.0. You can try this http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/

Comment: hmmmm...  since I sell my apps on Google Play I would need a comercial license for Genymotion??

Comment: Have you tried selecting Google Play API x86 option ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just setup an emulator with google play, should be one of the options when creating one.  If not present you may need to go into the sdk manager and get google play services and try again.

Comment: I have Google Play services and I selected a Google API for the emulator

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run an app in the emulator with Google Maps V2 API.
You must import Google Play Services library in your project, check if the library is correctly recognized and add your Google Map's API Key in AndroidManifest.

Regarding the import of Google Play Services Library you can found more information here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project
.

For check if the library is correctly recognized you can use the follow code:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();

        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But remember to initialize this constant:

```
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
```

Finally we can create you Google Maps V2 API Key follow these instructions:
[Google Map API KEY How To](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert)

.

And remember to add these instruction in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<!-- Google Map V2 Key TEST-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="GOOGLE-MAPS-API-KEY" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Good Luck!